# Button raised effect not working when background image attached

Tags: android, button

I am creating a simple button as follows :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edSearch"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Search"
    android:background="@color/md_green_500"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    />
```

Now, when i try add any image in background like :`android:background="@drawable/img123"` then button raise effect does not work. is there any way i can achieve raise effect with background image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a selector drawable for this. You need to provide 3 different images for this so that the button can toggle those images as per the state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal" />
<item android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_focused" />
</selector>
```

Also inspite of that you can use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) which will keep your image in center of button and the effects will be default as per operating system.

Comment: Yes this is known way. but why i cannot have raised button effect when image attached on button ?

Comment: Its because button has a default drawable. While applying image in background you override that drawable, so now you need to manage the states using custom drawable or by imagebutton.